# Android: add textview in a RelativeLayout in random position

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm adding some textview in a RelativeLayout called "number_container", this is my code but i don't see nothing, the textviews are not added...

```
private void labelAnimation(){

        TextView number = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        number.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Gang of Three.ttf");
        number.setTypeface(font);
        Random random = new Random();
        int random_size = random.nextInt(170 - 30) + 30;
        number.setTextSize(random_size);
        number.setTextColor(000000);
        int random_text = random.nextInt(10-1)+1;

        number.setText(Integer.toString(random_text));

        int random_width = random.nextInt(width_screen - 50) + 50;
        int random_height = random.nextInt(height_screen - 50) + 50;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(random_width, random_height, 0, 0);
        number.setLayoutParams(lp);
        number_container.addView(number);

        int random_delay = random.nextInt(800-100)+100;
        final Handler animation_sun = new Handler();
        animation_sun.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              labelAnimation();
          }
        }, random_delay);
    }
```

I tried also to remove the custom font but no good results.
What can I do?

Comment: a tried your code and works fine (without typeface, manually insert (width_screen and height_screen and settextcolor to color.WHITE (since my background is black :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the color of the textView...

```
number.setTextColor(color.WHITE);
```